# Horizontal scroll bar for div

Tags: html, css, scroll

Please find the [DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/gwUyn/).

I am trying to get the horizontal scroll to the div but in current code, only vertical scroll is appearing. I need all the ul list to be in the same line, means it should not come in second line so that I can get the horizontal scroll. http://jsfiddle.net/gwUyn/

How do I get the horizontal scroll?

Comment: Can you please add a short, working, simple example in your question, so the question in itself (without relying on external sites) will remain useful to future visitors?

Comment: I have adde the fiddle link. IN that fiddle if you scroll tthe result part to the end you can see the custom scroll for div

Comment: I know, and the fiddle is appreciated. However, I think [it's preferred](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80978/162730) that fiddle is used to *support* a question, and that the question can be understood on itself as well (which is why some code in the question as well would be great).

Comment: Check the fiddle I have posted below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On:

```
.horizontalaccordion > ul > li
```

Add:

```
dispaly:inline-block
```

Delete the:

```
dispaly:block
```

And your code will work

Answer (score 2):

You should use "overflow-x: scroll;" in the css id or class that your div belongs to.

> ##HTML FILE##
>      < div class="test">
>      all the text you want to write
>      < /div>
>
> ##CSS FILE##
>      .test{
>      width : 100px;
>      height: 100px;
>      overflow-x: scroll;
>      }

LINK EDITED

In your case it's particular but I think that you tried to do that : http://jsfiddle.net/5XCRL/

Comment: Plain html works but it is not working in my code. Pls check my fiddle

Comment: I dont want to add the fixed width. It should be 100% coz there will be many list coming up

Comment: Here is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/5XCRL/   If it's ok to you, you can validate the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There will never be a horizontal scroll bar, while your children elements fits into parent one. If i correctly understood your goal, this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwUyn/1/) may help you

**UPDATE:**

One more try: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwUyn/3/)

Comment: I need all the li to flow in one row. Now it is coming in 3 rows if you observe

Comment: @Sowmya Is a number of headings a known value? If it is, setting `.horizontalaccordion>ul` width in px may solve the problem